# ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series when trying to add rows dynamically in the dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am very new to Python and am trying to understand how this piece of code is adding rows to the dataframe dynamically. But upon trying I am observing issue

> ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series

what am I doing wrong here?

```
def return_most_common_venues(row, num_top_venues):
    row_categories = row
    row_categories_sorted = row_categories.sort_values(ascending=False)
    
    return row_categories_sorted.index.values[0:num_top_venues]

num_top_venues = 10

columns = ['Neighborhood','Total Number of Venues']
indicators = ['st', 'nd', 'rd']
# create columns according to number of top venues

for ind in np.arange(num_top_venues):
    try:
        columns.append('{}{} Most Common Restaurant'.format(ind+1, indicators[ind]))
    except:
        columns.append('{}th Most Common Restaurant'.format(ind+1))
#print(columns)
#create a new dataframe
venues_most = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)
for ind in range(venues_grouped.shape[0]):
#    venues_most.loc[ind, 'Neighborhood'] = venues_grouped.iloc[ind].Neighborhood
#    venues_most.loc[ind, 'Total Number of Venues'] = venues_grouped.iloc[ind,1:].sum()
#    venues_most.iloc[ind, 2:] = return_most_common_venues(venues_grouped.iloc[ind, 1:], num_top_venues)

venues_most.head()
```

updated - 12/01/2021
To begin with I am using One-hot encoding to cluster the neighborhoods to create the venues_grouped dataframe . Then I am trying to create the venues_most dataframe to populate most common venues . [how venues_grouped dataframe looks like][1]

I can see venues_most dataframe is getting created successfully but it's failing while populating the data from venues_most.here is the full Trace -

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-3a86bf95d17e> in <module>
     21 venues_most = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)
     22 for ind in range(venues_grouped.shape[0]):
---> 23     venues_most.loc[ind, 'Neighborhood'] = venues_grouped.iloc[ind].Neighborhood
     24     venues_most.loc[ind, 'Total Number of Venues'] = venues_grouped.iloc[ind,1:].sum()
     25     venues_most.iloc[ind, 2:] = return_most_common_venues(venues_grouped.iloc[ind, 1:], num_top_venues)

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.7-main/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    669             key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
    670         indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
--> 671         self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
    672 
    673     def _validate_key(self, key, axis: int):

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.7-main/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value)
   1053                 # setting for extensionarrays that store dicts. Need to decide
   1054                 # if it's worth supporting that.
-> 1055                 value = self._align_series(indexer, Series(value))
   1056 
   1057             elif isinstance(value, ABCDataFrame):

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.7-main/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _align_series(self, indexer, ser, multiindex_indexer)
   1214             return ser.reindex(ax)._values
   1215 
-> 1216         raise ValueError("Incompatible indexer with Series")
   1217 
   1218     def _align_frame(self, indexer, df: ABCDataFrame):

ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series
```

updated:12/01/2021
Table Sample for Venue grouped:

|  | Neighborhood | Trail | Theatre | Ice-Cream Shop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | B | 5 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | C | 2 | 6 | 5 |

Output I am expecting from venue_most is something like this

|  | Neighborood | TotalVenues | 1stcommonvenue | 2ndcommonvenue | 3rdcommon venue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 6 | Ice-Cream Shop | Theatre | Trail |
| 1 | B | 10 | Trail | Ice-Cream Shop | Theatre |
| 2 | C | 13 | Theatre | Ice-Cream Shop | Trail |

Comment: can you post some data to look at? And the full error trace?

Comment: Hello @JonathanLeon I have edited my main question with the error trace and what I am intending to achieve . I hope that helps . Thank you for responding.

Comment: getting closer. please paste the data for venues_grouped, not an image. also, what do you want venues_most to look like. it helps to understand where you're headed, as there may be a better way than your for loop.

Comment: Hello @JonathanLeon I just updated my question with two table samples . Hope that helps.

Comment: ah, that's a bit more involved than I first thought. the first two columns aren't difficult but ordering the venues by row will take some thought how to approach.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more elegant way to order the venues and map to the dataframe, but this works. First get the dictionary of venues, reverse sort by values, then add to the new dataframe.

```
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''    Neighborhood    Trail   Theatre Ice-CreamShop
A   1   2   3
B   5   1   4
C   2   6   5'''), sep='\s+', engine='python')

def order_venues(x):
    dfnew['Neighborhood'] = x['Neighborhood']
    dfnew['TotalVenues'] = x.iloc[:, 1:4].sum(axis=1)
    mydict = x.iloc[:, 1:4].to_dict(orient='records')[0]
    reverse_order = {k: v for k, v in sorted(mydict.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda item: item[1])}
    dfnew[['1stcommonvenue', '2ndcommonvenue', '3rdcommonvenue']] = list(reverse_order.keys())
    return dfnew

dfnew = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Neighborhood', 'TotalVenues', '1stcommonvenue', '2ndcommonvenue', '3rdcommonvenue'])
dfnew = df.groupby(df.index).apply(order_venues)
print(dfnew)
```

Outptut

```
    Neighborhood  TotalVenues 1stcommonvenue 2ndcommonvenue 3rdcommonvenue
0 0            A            6  Ice-CreamShop        Theatre          Trail
1 1            B           10          Trail  Ice-CreamShop        Theatre
2 2            C           13        Theatre  Ice-CreamShop          Trail
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . I will definitely give it a shot . But if you have any input of what exactly is wrong in my original code then probably that would be great as well.

Comment: I ran your code now that I have the data and it worked. I didn't get the error you had but I did have to change num_top_venues = 10 to 3  as there were only three venues. And your code is faster than mine, so kudos. I don't know why you are getting the error unless the datatypes between what you are providing here are different from you are working with.

Comment: ok ...that's interesting  because the data I gave is a very small example dataset . But actual dataset is supposed to have Venues of Toronto fetched using Foursquare API . So possibly I am having a Data Quality issue here .